# sort by dropdown queries custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Wanted to have a feature of a dropdown on my custom archive template like this https://facetwp.com/demo/cars/?_sort=title_asc
here is my code but doesnt sort any of the custom post either by title or for ratings.

```
<?php
 $order = "&order=ASC";
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'rmp_get_avg_rating') { $order = 
"&order=ASC&orderby=ratings";  }
  if ($_POST['select'] == 'title') { $order = 
"&order=ASC&orderby=title";  }
 ?>
 <form method="post" id="order">
 Sort by:
<select name="select" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="ratings"<?php selected( 
$_POST['select'],'rmp_get_avg_rating', 1 ); ?>>Highest Rated</option>
<option value="alphabetical"<?php selected( 
$_POST['select'],'alphabetical' , 1 ); ?>>Alphabetical</option>
</select>
</form>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 
array( 
    'post_type' => 'company',
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
   ); 
  ?>
 <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: You are not doing _anything_ with the value you are assigning to the variable `$order` anywhere later on, so what did you expect to happen - magic …?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to resolved this
here is the working code

```
    <?php
      $loop = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']) : 
       "";

      if(!empty($loop) && "title" == $loop):
       $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=>'company',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'orderby'=> "title",
        'order'=>'ASC',
        ));
         endif;

       if(!empty($loop) && "rmp_get_avg_rating" == $loop):
        $loop = new WP_Query(array(
           'post_type'=>'company',
           'posts_per_page'=>-1,
           'orderby'=> "rmp_get_avg_rating",
           'order'=>'ASC',
           ));
          endif;
          ?>
      <form method="GET">
        <select name="orderby" id="orderby">
          <option value="select">Select</option>
          <option value="rmp_get_avg_rating">Highest Rated</option>
          <option value="title">Alphabetical</option>
         </select>
         <button type="submit">Apply</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```